# Getting null pointer exception on when coming back to activity from another activity

Tags: android

I have a problem with saving state and restoring it. I have two variables that I want to save when another activity is started and restore them when I press home back button. There is no problem when I'm pressing soft back button. I'm getting null pointer exception on bundle.getString() method.

Thanks in advance.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            cat_id = savedInstanceState.getString("CATEGORY_ID");
            cat_name = savedInstanceState.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");
        }
        else
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            cat_id = extras.getString("CATEGORY_ID"); //here I'm getting an exception
            cat_name = extras.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");
        }


@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        outState.putString("CATEGORY_ID", state_category_id);
        outState.putString("CATEGORY_NAME", state_category_name);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: Check `if(extras != null)`

Comment: thank for the support.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    outState.putString("CATEGORY_ID", state_category_id);
    outState.putString("CATEGORY_NAME", state_category_name);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And Retrieve data after getting back from different activity :

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("CATEGORY_ID")) {
            cat_id = extras.getString("CATEGORY_ID"); 
        }

       if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("CATEGORY_NAME")) {
           cat_name = extras.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");
       }

    }

    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put this condition in else part

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("CATEGORY_ID"))
    cat_id = extras.getString("CATEGORY_ID");
else
    cat_id=//assign default id

if(getIntent().hasExtra("CATEGORY_NAME"))
    cat_name = extras.getString("CATEGORY_NAME");
else
    cat_name=//assign default name
```

Comment: Actually I need to query data from database for the category_id so I need it to be there

Comment: ok then do your coding part when you are not getting CATEGORY_ID or CATEGORY_NAME

Comment: when you are not getting CATEGORY_ID from your intent extras, it will move to else condition

Comment: So I don't need to save instance?

Comment: If you want it you can keep it, i just gave answer for your nullpointer

Comment: Thanks you. but it's not solving my problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96257/discussion-between-ravi-rupareliya-and-aram).

Comment: yes but it will not give you NllPointerException, you just asked reason for your exception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your support.

Actually I solved problem by storing needed data in static variables and getting them when bundle is null.

Thanks again.