# onActivityresult data is null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

this is my camera app in which i want to capture image and crop it but it take picture is save in my ""myimage" directory but does't perform the crop functionality. please i need a help i am an new this field 
this is my camera open source code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyImage");             
file.mkdir();          
String timestmp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());      

File images = new File(file, "QR_" + timestmp + ".jpg");
Urisavedmsg=Uri.fromFile(images); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Urisavedmsg);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_Code);
```

**And this is my Activity result code here else executed is any thing else**

```
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_Code && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK )
        if (Urisavedmsg!=null)
        {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/Myimage");

            if (Urisavedmsg!=null){
                try {
                    Uri getImage;
                    getImage=data.getData();
                    cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(file));
                    cropCapturedImage(getImage);


                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    String msg = "sorry your device does't support the crop the action!";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();


                }}
            if (requestCode == 2) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap thepic = bundle.getParcelable("data");
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(thepic);

            }


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some thing worng", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
}
```

**Here is my crop method .....**

```
private void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri) {
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

       cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, Crop_pic);
    }
```

Comment: `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not mandatory for Android system. There is no default app to handle it. Some android devices have a crop application, but far not all of them.

Comment: Also what is null actually? is it `Urisavedmsg`?

Comment: i think onActivityResult() is in your fragment , may be after the crop process onactivity result in the Activity which hold the fragment is invoked,that's why result null

Comment: Try implementing `onSaveInstance()` and `onRestoreInstance`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33938950/3140227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, it works for me properly in fragment, change code accordingly if you are performing action in Activity class.

```
File file = new File(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/picture").getPath());
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.mkdirs();
                    }
capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile("myImages" + new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()), ".jpg", file));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

**Now onActivityResult**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Util.REQUEST_CAMERA:
                try {
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) && !Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY)) {
                        File file = new File(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "./myImages"+ File.separator+ "picture").getPath());
                        if (!file.exists()) {
                            file.mkdirs();
                        }

                        selectedPath1 = File.createTempFile("myImages"+ new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyHHmmss",Locale.US).format(new Date()),".jpg", file).toString();
                        croppedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(selectedPath1));

                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                        intent.setDataAndType(capturedImageUri, "image/*");
                        intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
                        intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
                        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                        intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                        intent.putExtra("output", croppedImageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, Util.REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE);
        } else {
                        Toast.show(getActivity(), "Please insert memory card to take pictures and make sure it is write able");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case Util.REQUEST_CROP_IMAGE:
                Logg.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Profile_Pic ===== " + selectedPath1);
                imgProfile.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://" + croppedImageUri));

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Same functionality i have done in my application below is the code.
    //Use this method to open camera 

        private void takePictureFromCamera() {
            imageFile = CameraUtil.getOutputMediaFile(1);
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            try {
                Uri mImageCaptureUri = null;
                final String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                }
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) 
                    {
                         //Exception Handling
                    }}

//Use this method to start crop functionality

            private void startCropImage() {
            if (getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing() &&              imageFile != null) {
                final int rotation = CameraUtil.checkExIfInfo(imageFile.getPath());
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFile(imageFile, imageTemp);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CropImage.class);
                intent.putExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH, imageFile.getPath());
                intent.putExtra(CropImage.SCALE, true);
                intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_X, 2);
                intent.putExtra(CropImage.ASPECT_Y, 2);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE);
            }
        }


//activity_cropimage.xml

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#2a3442"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <view
            android:id="@+id/activty_crop_image_imageView"
            class="com.bcgsearch.simplecrop.CropImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_crop_image_linearLayout"
            android:layout_x="@dimen/dimen_zero_dp"
            android:layout_y="@dimen/dimen_zero_dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_crop_image_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_crop_image_ivClearCrop"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_zero_dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_five_dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_crop_image" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Select specific area of image"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_default_font"
                custom:font_name="@string/font_opensans_regular" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_crop_image_ivSaveCrop"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_zero_dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_five_dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_done_image_crop" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

  //On Activity Result for Capture camera image and crop image
     @Override
         public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE:
                    startCropImage();
                    break;
                case REQUEST_CODE_CROP_IMAGE:
                    final String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);
                    profilePictureUrl = imageFile.toString();
                    if (path == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Picasso.with(getActivity())
                            .load(imageFile)
                            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_loader)
                            .fit()
                            .centerCrop()
                            .into(imageViewLogo);
                    break;
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

    Hope this will help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Because of character limit this crop image class is as below.

  //Crop Image Class
        public class CropImage extends MonitoredActivity
         {
           final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1024;
            private static final String TAG = "CropImage";
            public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "image-path";
            public static final String SCALE = "scale";
            public static final String ORIENTATION_IN_DEGREES = "orientation_in_degrees";
            public static final String ASPECT_X = "aspectX";
            public static final String ASPECT_Y = "aspectY";
            public static final String OUTPUT_X = "outputX";
            public static final String OUTPUT_Y = "outputY";
            public static final String SCALE_UP_IF_NEEDED = "scaleUpIfNeeded";
            public static final String CIRCLE_CROP = "circleCrop";
            public static final String RETURN_DATA = "return-data";
            public static final String RETURN_DATA_AS_BITMAP = "data";
            public static final String ACTION_INLINE_DATA = "inline-data";

            // These are various options can be specified in the intent.
            private Bitmap.CompressFormat mOutputFormat = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
            private Uri mSaveUri = null;
            private boolean mDoFaceDetection = true;
            private boolean mCircleCrop = false;
            private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

            private int mAspectX;
            private int mAspectY;
            private int mOutputX;
            private int mOutputY;
            private boolean mScale;
            private CropImageView mImageView;
            private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
            private Bitmap mBitmap;
            private String mImagePath;

            boolean mWaitingToPick; // Whether we are wait the user to pick a face.
            boolean mSaving;  // Whether the "save" button is already clicked.
            HighlightView mCrop;

            // These options specifiy the output image size and whether we should
            // scale the output to fit it (or just crop it).
            private boolean mScaleUp = true;

            private final BitmapManager.ThreadSet mDecodingThreads =
                    new BitmapManager.ThreadSet();

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

                super.onCreate(icicle);
                mContentResolver = getContentResolver();

                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_cropimage);

                mImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.activty_crop_image_imageView);

                showStorageToast(this);

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                if (extras != null) {

                    if (extras.getString(CIRCLE_CROP) != null) {

                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                            mImageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                        }

                        mCircleCrop = true;
                        mAspectX = 1;
                        mAspectY = 1;
                    }

                    mImagePath = extras.getString(IMAGE_PATH);

                    mSaveUri = getImageUri(mImagePath);
                    mBitmap = getBitmap(mImagePath);

                    if (extras.containsKey(ASPECT_X) && extras.get(ASPECT_X) instanceof Integer) {

                        mAspectX = extras.getInt(ASPECT_X);
                    } else {

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("aspect_x must be integer");
                    }
                    if (extras.containsKey(ASPECT_Y) && extras.get(ASPECT_Y) instanceof Integer) {

                        mAspectY = extras.getInt(ASPECT_Y);
                    } else {

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("aspect_y must be integer");
                    }
                    mOutputX = extras.getInt(OUTPUT_X);
                    mOutputY = extras.getInt(OUTPUT_Y);
                    mScale = extras.getBoolean(SCALE, true);
                    mScaleUp = extras.getBoolean(SCALE_UP_IF_NEEDED, true);
                }


                if (mBitmap == null) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "finish!!!");
                    finish();
                    return;
                }

                // Make UI fullscreen.
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

                findViewById(R.id.activity_crop_image_ivClearCrop).setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

                findViewById(R.id.activity_crop_image_ivSaveCrop).setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                try {
                                    onSaveClicked();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                startFaceDetection();
            }

            private Uri getImageUri(String path) {

                return Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
            }

            private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

                Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
                InputStream in = null;
                try {
                    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

                    //Decode image size
                    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
                    in.close();

                    int scale = 1;
                    if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
                        scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
                    }

                    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
                    in.close();

                    return b;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "file " + path + " not found");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "file " + path + " not found");
                }
                return null;
            }


            private void startFaceDetection() {

                if (isFinishing()) {
                    return;
                }

                mImageView.setImageBitmapResetBase(mBitmap, true);

                Util.startBackgroundJob(this, null,
                        "Please wait\u2026",
                        new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                                final Bitmap b = mBitmap;
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                        if (b != mBitmap && b != null) {
                                            mImageView.setImageBitmapResetBase(b, true);
                                            mBitmap.recycle();
                                            mBitmap = b;
                                        }
                                        if (mImageView.getScale() == 1F) {
                                            mImageView.center(true, true);
                                        }
                                        latch.countDown();
                                    }
                                });
                                try {
                                    latch.await();
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                                }
                                mRunFaceDetection.run();
                            }
                        }, mHandler);
            }


            private void onSaveClicked() throws Exception {
                // TODO this code needs to change to use the decode/crop/encode single
                // step api so that we don't require that the whole (possibly large)
                // bitmap doesn't have to be read into memory
                if (mSaving)
                    return;

                if (mCrop == null) {

                    return;
                }

                mSaving = true;

                Rect r = mCrop.getCropRect();

                int width = r.width();
                int height = r.height();

                // If we are circle cropping, we want alpha channel, which is the
                // third param here.
                Bitmap croppedImage;
                try {

                    croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                            mCircleCrop ? Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 : Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e;
                }
                if (croppedImage == null) {

                    return;
                }

                {
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedImage);
                    Rect dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, r, dstRect, null);
                }

                if (mCircleCrop) {

                    // OK, so what's all this about?
                    // Bitmaps are inherently rectangular but we want to return
                    // something that's basically a circle.  So we fill in the
                    // area around the circle with alpha.  Note the all important
                    // PortDuff.Mode.CLEAR.
                    Canvas c = new Canvas(croppedImage);
                    Path p = new Path();
                    p.addCircle(width / 2F, height / 2F, width / 2F,
                            Path.Direction.CW);
                    c.clipPath(p, Region.Op.DIFFERENCE);
                    c.drawColor(0x00000000, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                }

                /* If the output is required to a specific size then scale or fill */
                if (mOutputX != 0 && mOutputY != 0) {

                    if (mScale) {

                        /* Scale the image to the required dimensions */
                        Bitmap old = croppedImage;
                        croppedImage = Util.transform(new Matrix(),
                                croppedImage, mOutputX, mOutputY, mScaleUp);
                        if (old != croppedImage) {

                            old.recycle();
                        }
                    } else {

                        /* Don't scale the image crop it to the size requested.
                         * Create an new image with the cropped image in the center and
                         * the extra space filled.
                         */

                        // Don't scale the image but instead fill it so it's the
                        // required dimension
                        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOutputX, mOutputY,
                                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);

                        Rect srcRect = mCrop.getCropRect();
                        Rect dstRect = new Rect(0, 0, mOutputX, mOutputY);

                        int dx = (srcRect.width() - dstRect.width()) / 2;
                        int dy = (srcRect.height() - dstRect.height()) / 2;

                        /* If the srcRect is too big, use the center part of it. */
                        srcRect.inset(Math.max(0, dx), Math.max(0, dy));

                        /* If the dstRect is too big, use the center part of it. */
                        dstRect.inset(Math.max(0, -dx), Math.max(0, -dy));

                        /* Draw the cropped bitmap in the center */
                        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, dstRect, null);

                        /* Set the cropped bitmap as the new bitmap */
                        croppedImage.recycle();
                        croppedImage = b;
                    }
                }

                // Return the cropped image directly or save it to the specified URI.
                Bundle myExtras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (myExtras != null && (myExtras.getParcelable("data") != null
                        || myExtras.getBoolean(RETURN_DATA))) {

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putParcelable(RETURN_DATA_AS_BITMAP, croppedImage);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,
                            (new Intent()).setAction(ACTION_INLINE_DATA).putExtras(extras));
                    finish();
                } else {
                    final Bitmap b = croppedImage;
                    Util.startBackgroundJob(this, null, getString(R.string.crop_image_saving_image),
                            new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    saveOutput(b);
                                }
                            }, mHandler);
                }
            }

            private void saveOutput(Bitmap croppedImage) {

                if (mSaveUri != null) {
                    OutputStream outputStream = null;
                    try {
                        outputStream = mContentResolver.openOutputStream(mSaveUri);
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            croppedImage.compress(mOutputFormat, 90, outputStream);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot open file: " + mSaveUri, ex);
                        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                        finish();
                        return;
                    } finally {

                        Util.closeSilently(outputStream);
                    }

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mSaveUri.toString());
                    intent.putExtras(extras);
                    intent.putExtra(IMAGE_PATH, mImagePath);
                    intent.putExtra(ORIENTATION_IN_DEGREES, Util.getOrientationInDegree(this));
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                } else {

                    Log.e(TAG, "not defined image url");
                }
                croppedImage.recycle();
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {

                super.onPause();
                BitmapManager.instance().cancelThreadDecoding(mDecodingThreads);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDestroy() {

                super.onDestroy();

                if (mBitmap != null) {

                    mBitmap.recycle();
                }
            }


            Runnable mRunFaceDetection = new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
                float mScale = 1F;
                Matrix mImageMatrix;
                FaceDetector.Face[] mFaces = new FaceDetector.Face[3];
                int mNumFaces;

                // For each face, we create a HightlightView for it.
                private void handleFace(FaceDetector.Face f) {

                    PointF midPoint = new PointF();

                    int r = ((int) (f.eyesDistance() * mScale)) * 2;
                    f.getMidPoint(midPoint);
                    midPoint.x *= mScale;
                    midPoint.y *= mScale;

                    int midX = (int) midPoint.x;
                    int midY = (int) midPoint.y;

                    HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);

                    int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
                    int height = mBitmap.getHeight();

                    Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

                    RectF faceRect = new RectF(midX, midY, midX, midY);
                    faceRect.inset(-r, -r);
                    if (faceRect.left < 0) {
                        faceRect.inset(-faceRect.left, -faceRect.left);
                    }

                    if (faceRect.top < 0) {
                        faceRect.inset(-faceRect.top, -faceRect.top);
                    }

                    if (faceRect.right > imageRect.right) {
                        faceRect.inset(faceRect.right - imageRect.right,
                                faceRect.right - imageRect.right);
                    }

                    if (faceRect.bottom > imageRect.bottom) {
                        faceRect.inset(faceRect.bottom - imageRect.bottom,
                                faceRect.bottom - imageRect.bottom);
                    }

                    hv.setup(mImageMatrix, imageRect, faceRect, mCircleCrop,
                            mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0);

                    mImageView.add(hv);
                }

                // Create a default HightlightView if we found no face in the picture.
                private void makeDefault() {

                    HighlightView hv = new HighlightView(mImageView);

                    int width = mBitmap.getWidth();
                    int height = mBitmap.getHeight();

                    Rect imageRect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

                    // make the default size about 4/5 of the width or height
                    int cropWidth = Math.min(width, height) * 4 / 5;
                    int cropHeight = cropWidth;

                    if (mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0) {

                        if (mAspectX > mAspectY) {

                            cropHeight = cropWidth * mAspectY / mAspectX;
                        } else {

                            cropWidth = cropHeight * mAspectX / mAspectY;
                        }
                    }

                    int x = (width - cropWidth) / 2;
                    int y = (height - cropHeight) / 2;

                    RectF cropRect = new RectF(x, y, x + cropWidth, y + cropHeight);
                    hv.setup(mImageMatrix, imageRect, cropRect, mCircleCrop,
                            mAspectX != 0 && mAspectY != 0);

                    mImageView.mHighlightViews.clear(); // Thong added for rotate

                    mImageView.add(hv);
                }

                // Scale the image down for faster face detection.
                private Bitmap prepareBitmap() {

                    if (mBitmap == null) {

                        return null;
                    }

                    // 256 pixels wide is enough.
                    if (mBitmap.getWidth() > 256) {

                        mScale = 256.0F / mBitmap.getWidth();
                    }
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.setScale(mScale, mScale);
                    return Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                }

                public void run() {

                    mImageMatrix = mImageView.getImageMatrix();
                    Bitmap faceBitmap = prepareBitmap();

                    mScale = 1.0F / mScale;
                    if (faceBitmap != null && mDoFaceDetection) {
                        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(faceBitmap.getWidth(),
                                faceBitmap.getHeight(), mFaces.length);
                        mNumFaces = detector.findFaces(faceBitmap, mFaces);
                    }

                    if (faceBitmap != null && faceBitmap != mBitmap) {
                        faceBitmap.recycle();
                    }

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            mWaitingToPick = mNumFaces > 1;
                            if (mNumFaces > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < mNumFaces; i++) {
                                    handleFace(mFaces[i]);
                                }
                            } else {
                                makeDefault();
                            }
                            mImageView.invalidate();
                            if (mImageView.mHighlightViews.size() == 1) {
                                mCrop = mImageView.mHighlightViews.get(0);
                                mCrop.setFocus(true);
                            }

                            if (mNumFaces > 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(CropImage.this,
                                        "Multi face crop help",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            public static final int NO_STORAGE_ERROR = -1;
            public static final int CANNOT_STAT_ERROR = -2;

            public static void showStorageToast(Activity activity) {

                showStorageToast(activity, calculatePicturesRemaining(activity));
            }

            public static void showStorageToast(Activity activity, int remaining) {

                String noStorageText = null;

                if (remaining == NO_STORAGE_ERROR) {

                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_CHECKING)) {

                        noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.preparing_card);
                    } else {

                        noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.no_storage_card);
                    }
                } else if (remaining < 1) {

                    noStorageText = activity.getString(R.string.not_enough_space);
                }

                if (noStorageText != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, noStorageText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            public static int calculatePicturesRemaining(Activity activity) {

                try {
                    /*if (!ImageManager.hasStorage()) {
                        return NO_STORAGE_ERROR;
                    } else {*/
                    String storageDirectory = "";
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                        storageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    } else {
                        storageDirectory = activity.getFilesDir().toString();
                    }
                    StatFs stat = new StatFs(storageDirectory);
                    float remaining = ((float) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                            * (float) stat.getBlockSize()) / 400000F;
                    return (int) remaining;
                    //}
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // if we can't stat the filesystem then we don't know how many
                    // pictures are remaining.  it might be zero but just leave it
                    // blank since we really don't know.
                    return CANNOT_STAT_ERROR;
                }
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CropImage Class use this activity

//Monitored Activity
             public class MonitoredActivity extends Activity {

                private final ArrayList<LifeCycleListener> mListeners =
                        new ArrayList<LifeCycleListener>();

                public interface LifeCycleListener {

                    void onActivityCreated(MonitoredActivity activity);

                    void onActivityDestroyed(MonitoredActivity activity);

                    void onActivityPaused(MonitoredActivity activity);

                    void onActivityResumed(MonitoredActivity activity);

                    void onActivityStarted(MonitoredActivity activity);

                    void onActivityStopped(MonitoredActivity activity);
                }

                public static class LifeCycleAdapter implements LifeCycleListener {
                enter code here
                    public void onActivityCreated(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }

                    public void onActivityDestroyed(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }

                    public void onActivityPaused(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }

                    public void onActivityResumed(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }

                    public void onActivityStarted(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }

                    public void onActivityStopped(MonitoredActivity activity) {

                    }
                }

                public void addLifeCycleListener(LifeCycleListener listener) {

                    if (mListeners.contains(listener)) return;
                    mListeners.add(listener);
                }

                public void removeLifeCycleListener(LifeCycleListener listener) {

                    mListeners.remove(listener);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    for (LifeCycleListener listener : mListeners) {
                        listener.onActivityCreated(this);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onDestroy() {

                    super.onDestroy();
                    for (LifeCycleListener listener : mListeners) {
                        listener.onActivityDestroyed(this);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onStart() {

                    super.onStart();
                    for (LifeCycleListener listener : mListeners) {
                        listener.onActivityStarted(this);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected void onStop() {

                    super.onStop();
                    for (LifeCycleListener listener : mListeners) {
                        listener.onActivityStopped(this);
                    }
                }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run Following Code: It works like a charm. TESTED!

// In onCreate:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_Code);
```

// In OnactivityResult:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_Code && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        timestmp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyImage");
        filename.mkdir();
                try {
                    images = new File(filename, "QR_" + timestmp + ".jpg");
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(images);
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageToSave = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                    imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    cropCapturedImage(Uri.fromFile(images));

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    String msg = "sorry your device does't support the crop the action!";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();

                }

    }
    else if (requestCode == 2) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeUriAsBitmap(Uri.fromFile(images)));  `// Here you can`enter code here` do whatever you want, with the image.`
    }
}
```

// YOUR Crop Image Code:

```
private void cropCapturedImage(Uri picUri) {

try {

    Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
}
// respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    // display an error message
    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

// Decode bitmap from uri

```
private Bitmap decodeUriAsBitmap(Uri uri){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```